# Deploying angular apps without displaying bindings on the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to ask whether there is a way to deploy the angular apps i.e. (modules, controllers, factories) and the bindings so that when users would inspect it or view page source on their browsers they're shown the html and not the bindings like for example {{persons.name}}, {{persons.email}}.

Even when we use ng-bind or ng-bind-template we have our model objects displayed in the code inspection or view page source views of browser.

Understandably the framework it self is based on Java script to start with and the scripts are required on the page, but my question is that is there a way to hide the underlying model architecture in the controller or factories written for some app ?

Can we use some technique for building our scripts and executing them on run time instead while our app initializes and not make code (in our scripts) and bindings (in our html) observable to the users ?

I have done a bit of searching and haven't yet found a suitable solution, most of the articles and references regarding Angular point towards it's core concepts instead.

I have recently started working on Angular so I'm trying to do things the right way as I have a jQuery background.

Comment: Try to use ng-cloak https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to know if you can pre-render angular.  While there are some technologies that do this, it is for the sake of search engine optimization, not for end-user use.  This is because AngularJS is run client-side.  If you have to pre-render it, you completely defeat the purpose of having it (honestly, you should just go with some other technology that does server-side rendering).

If you want to 'hide' your angular code, about all you can do there is minify it with something like uglify.  This will make your angular code incredibly difficult to work with, and smaller for the end-user to download.  There is an additional 'mangle' capability that uglify offers, but my understanding is that it is difficult or impossible to get it to work with angular due to some of angular's peculiarities regarding dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

To hide bindings like `{{persons.name}}` during page loading just add the `ng-cloak` class to your container (don't forget to add angular css file to your page), Angular will display it when everything is loaded.

You can't, as far as I know, hide your directive in your html code, but honestly I don't think it's really a problem, in front-end development your code is anyway always observable.

Comment: Thanks #Kaz. This'll do for the view. What about the scripts ?

Comment: Well you can always minify or obfuscate your script by using a front end tool like Grunt or Gulp, but it's more about saving some loading times than hiding the code to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No
its not possible to hide the underlying model since Javascript is interpreted at client side it will always be possible to view the underlying model.

However you can also view the interpreted version of your HTML with firebug or any other debugging tool